# Position Fixed and iFrame on Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, mobile, iframe, safari, css-position

I have been able to get position: fixed working perfectly on a div outside an iFrame, but once it is loaded in an iFrame, position:fixed doesn't work anymore.

Is this a know issue (I haven't been able to find anything on the topic) or am I missing out an important piece of CSS, or meta viewport information? Is there a way to work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Ugh... I'm also experiencing the exact same thing, and it's been more than a year since your post.  >.<  I'm beginning to hate iOs phones. >.<

Also, this issue happens in Chrome on iOs.  (i.e., any browser that you use in an iOs mobile system.

Comment: Any solution to this?