# Why does `position:fixed` not work when viewed in an `iframe` using an iPhone or iOS device?

Tags: ios, css, iframe, css-position

I've looked into stackoverflow and it seems that [`position:fixed` in an iframe for iOS mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874910/position-fixed-and-iframe-on-mobile-safari) has been an issue in the past but have yet to have an answer.

Here's an example I created via jsbin: http://jsbin.com/pekeca/1/

In that example, there is a parent HTML page that uses iframe which contains another HTML page (child).  Here are the things to note:

- When the parent HTML is viewed on any device, the navigation bar in the child HTML stays fixed.  This is the intended behavior.
- However, when the parent HTML is viewed on an iPhone regardless of the browser, the navigation bar in the child HTML loses its fixed position.  **This is a bug** that only happens in iPhones.
- When the [child HTML page is viewed directly (i.e., not inside an iframe)](http://jsbin.com/majab/1/) in an iPhone, the navigation bar stays in a fixed position and works fine.

Has anyone figured out a workaround for `position:fixed` in iPhones or iOS devices?

Comment: I am getting the same issue, have you found any workarounds yet?

Comment: @Shuvro, nope and I've stopped working on it further.  However, a friend of mine sent me [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083462/how-to-get-an-iframe-to-be-responsive-in-ios-safari), but I have yet to try it.  It's not directly related to the issue, but may provide some insight.

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix the problem, but it's a very useful solution to other iOS iframe issues, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome and Safari on iOS it seems the issue here is not the fixed position, but with the height of the iframe. From another SO answer: "Starting in version 4.2.1 of Safari iOS, and still going as of 4.3.3, the entire content of an iFrame is forcibly shown."

These other posts might help you:

- iframe on iOS (iPad) content cropping issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10816492/1359306
- iFrame and Mobile Safari (iPad/iPhone) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19667786/1359306